# Complex regex to replace commas with dots for quoted values then remove quotes

Tags: regex, perl

I have some csv files which have been incorrectly exported. Some fields containing numbers have been incorrectly exported as Strings with the decimal place as a comma instead of a dot.

Here's a couple of examples:

`"GREEN,"15,4",55,"15,5",64,"17,0","18,9",107,145,21,38,
"BLUE","15,1",46,"15,2",51,"11,4","13,5",89,96,25,7,`

So, I want to switch the commas to dots for numbers in quotation marks and then remove the quotation marks from all numbers.

Can anyone help me out here please?

Comment: If you show you've made an attempt to solve this yourself you'll find people will be much more generous in helping you

Comment: Your example is **confusing** which numbers are  surrounded by quotations ?

Comment: @Meninx I guess the values like `"15,4"` should become `15.4` without the quotation marks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a CSV parser, and this becomes easy:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new( { binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 } );

while ( my $row = $csv->getline( \*DATA ) ) {
   s/,/./ for @$row;
   $csv->say( \*STDOUT, $row );
}


__DATA__
"GREEN","15,4",55,"15,5",64,"17,0","18,9",107,145,21,38,
"BLUE","15,1",46,"15,2",51,"11,4","13,5",89,96,25,7,
```

Example above uses inlined data to make it runnable standalone - you'll probably want to use an input and output file instead of `DATA` and `STDOUT`.

If you're particularly wanting to keep the quotes around the 'strings' but not the 'numbers', then you can make use of `keep_meta_info` or just re-add them when they're needed.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the right solution!

Comment: Maybe cos the regex is too generic and could match a legitimate string?

Answer (score 2):

```
,(?!(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

You can use this remove `,` between `"`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/t5Euq1/1

Comment: Why downvoted ?

Comment: Thanks for the link - awesome site ;o). I even did not have the privilege to get the quotes  around the digits , thus https://regex101.com/r/t5Euq1/6 `([;]?["]*[0-9]+)[,]([0-9]+["]*[;]?)`